# How to check the ranges of numbers in ANTLR 3?

Tags: java, python, parsing, antlr, antlr3

I know this might end up being language specific, so a Java or Python solution would be acceptable.

Given the grammar:

```
MONTH   : DIGIT DIGIT ;
DIGIT   : ('0'..'9') ;
```

I want a check constraint on `MONTH` to ensure the value is between `01` and `12`. Where do I start looking, and how do I specify this constraint as a rule?

Comment: That depends on what other tokens are defined. What should `13` be tokenized as?

Comment: Anything `< 1` and `> 12` should throw an error in this case, this will be embedded in another rule that specifies `MONTH` in the middle of its rule for the formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed custom code by wrapping `{` and `}` around it. So you could do something like:

```
MONTH 
  :  DIGIT DIGIT 
     {
       int month = Integer.parseInt(getText());
       // do your check here
     } 
  ;
```

As you can see, I called [`getText()`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/classorg_1_1antlr_1_1runtime_1_1_common_token.html#ed2313fcd4f2161efcd7a9d306594b47) to get a hold of the matched text of the token.

Note that I assumed you're referencing this `MONTH` rule from another lexer rule. If you're going to throw an exception if `1 > month > 12`, then whenever your source contains an illegal month value, non of the parser rules will ever be matched. Although lexer- and parser rules can be mixed in one `.g` grammar file, the input source is first tokenized based on the lexer rules, and once that has happened, only then the parser rules will be matched.

Comment: I could not get the `super.getText()` call to work; `$month.text` did work. But I am having my doubts about putting date parsing logic in my grammar, the ISO 8061 spec get pretty convoluted if you try and support all the optional symbols and edge cases.

Comment: @Jarrod, hmm, perhaps ANTLR only accepts `getText()` without the `super` keyword. Didn't test it, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this free online utility [Regex_For_Range](http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range) to generate a regular expression for any continuous integer range.  For the values 01-12 (with allowed leading 0's) the utility gives:

```
0*([1-9]|1[0-2])
```

From here you can see that if you want to constrain this to just the 2-digit strings '01' through '12', then adjust this to read:

```
0[1-9]|1[0-2]
```

For days 01-31 we get:

```
0*([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])
```

And for the years 2000-2099 the expression is simply:

```
20[0-9]{2}
```

Comment: as hacky and geeky cool as this is, this bothers me as a maintenance nightmare in more ways than one, and ANTLR doesn't use regular expressions to match, it is an LL parser. I can't possibly see where this would be better than using a native language numeric comparison which would be self documenting. **If you have a problem and solve it with regular expressions now you have two problems!**